# Delete Google Sheet files created with service account as a regular user

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api, google-api-python-client

I'm using the [gspread](https://pypi.org/project/gspread/) library to connect to the Google Sheets API v4 API in order to create new Google Sheets with a service account. I share the Sheets with a user who can read and write to the files. But the user cannot delete them. I can not transfer the owner rights to the user, if I try I get this error message:

> Ownership can only be transferred to another user in the same domain as the current owner

So now I have a lot of Google Sheet files on my Google Drive that the user cannot delete.
How do I solve this?

```
import os, gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

credsFile = self.getString('credentialsJsonFile')

credsPathAndFileName = os.path.join(GetStringValue('System.Profile'), credsFile)

SCOPES = ["https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds",'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]
creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(credsPathAndFileName, SCOPES)

gc = gspread.authorize(creds)
sheetName = self.getStringValue('spreadsheetFileName')
sh = gc.create(sheetName)

shareUser1 = self.getStringValue('shareWithUser1')
shareGroup1 = self.getStringValue('shareWithGroup1')
if not shareUser1 == '':
  sh.share(shareUser1, perm_type='user', role='owner')
if not shareGroup1 == '':
  sh.share(shareGroup1, perm_type='group', role='owner')

worksheet = sh.get_worksheet(0)

worksheet.update_acell('A4', 'X-Mean')
worksheet.update_acell('A5', 'X-STD')
```

Comment: I don't know about the gspread API, but if you post your code, even people that doesn't know it might help you. Just a tip if you want to increase the chance to have an answer.

Comment: Did you want to create the spreadsheets in your google drive or would it be better to create them on the user’s drive? Do you know how to create them on the user’s drive? Do you and the user have different email domains, for example `you@gmail.com` and `user@someplace.com`?

Comment: I want the spreadsheets to be located in our shared Google Drive. The service accounts e-mail adress is something@projectname.iam.gserviceaccount.com and the users e-mail is on another domain. I want the users of the Google Drive to be able to delete the files created by the service account used by the API.

Comment: The code you have included doesn't have anything to do with permissions transfer of a file.  Please post the code that shows the issue you are having.

Comment: Ok, changed role from 'writer' to 'owner'.

Comment: Do you mean that changing the role solved your issue?

Comment: No, I changed the code to owner, that's what gives me the error that the ownership can't be transferred.

Comment: @JonathanJohansson did you ever solve this?  I am running into the same issue!